# My C# SQL Select statement is not picking up any records in my table

Tags: sql, select

I have *4 records* in my SQL table that and I'm doing a SQL select statement to select records based on a certain criteria but I'm not picking any records up. Can someone please help?

Here is my SELECT statement:

```
string Sql = "";  
Sql = @"SELECT * FROM " + _dtlName + " 
        WHERE Shipper_No = '" + sidNo + "' 
        AND Job_Code != '" + "R" + "'";
```

I have 3 records that have a `Null` for `Job_Code` and `1` record that has an `R`.

Based on that, I should pickup the *3 records with the NULL* `Job_Code` but it *returns 0 records*.

Comment: Have you tested the SQL directly into your DB with some expected parameters? And have you output your SQL string to make sure it matched the working test case?

Comment: try getting rid of the Shipper_No part of the where clause to make sure that's not the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that a comparison between any non-null value and a null value doesn't return a value of true or false, but null. So your query should probably be:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + _dtlName + " WHERE Shipper_No = @ShipperNo " +
             "AND (Job_Code IS NULL OR Job_Code != 'R')";
```

(Note that I've extracted a parameter for `Shipper_No` - you shouldn't be including values directly in your SQL like that. Obviously you'll need to then set the parameter value in the SQL command.)

Also note that `<>` is more common in SQL to represent "not equal to", but I believe T-SQL allows either form.

Comment: Thank you Jon that worked great! One thing though, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by Shipper_No = @ShipperNo? Isn't that the same as setting up the value in my parameter "sidNo"?

Comment: @hmakled: No, it's not. Your code puts the value *straight into the SQL*. My code puts a *placeholder* in the SQL, then passes the value separately. That means the value can contain any data it wants (including quotes) without it affecting the code in the SQL at all. Using parameterized SQL has a number of benefits - primarily avoiding SQL Injection Attacks. See http://bobby-tables.com

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Sql = @"SELECT * FROM " + _dtlName + " WHERE Shipper_No = '" + sidNo + "' AND Job_Code NOT IN ('R')";
```

Comment: Hey Jim thanks for the feed back. I couldn't get the "Job_Code NOT IN ('R')" to work though. Kept getting an error saying something about ('R')

Answer (score 0):

I think your query should be more like this since you want to select the `NULL` values.

```
string Sql = String.Format("SELECT * " + 
                           "FROM {0} " +
                           "WHERE Shipper_No = {1} AND " +
                           "      Job_Code IS NULL",
                            _dtlName, sidNo)
```